# How to Setup a new password while opening csv file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, security, password-protection

How to add password authentication to `csv` file without using any 3rd party library, I have done for `excel` using library `apache.poi`

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Xlsx {

 public static void doEncrypt(String data) throws Exception {

  POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
  EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);

  Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
  enc.confirmPassword("vinay");

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(data);

  // write the workbook into the encrypted OutputStream
  OutputStream encos = enc.getDataStream(fs);
  workbook.write(encos);
  workbook.close();
  encos.close(); // this is necessary before writing out the FileSystem

  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/home/nspl/Documents/Tested/QW1232X.xlsx");
  fs.writeFilesystem(os);
  os.close();
  fs.close();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  doEncrypt("Test");
  System.out.println("COMPLETED");
 }
}
```

Comment: afaik you don't. Excel has the ability to set a password for xls or xlsx. There is no such thing for a plain text file (which is what csv files are).

Comment: What do you mean?? An excel document is actually a zip of XML files - zip natively supports encryption and so you can use POI to enable password protection just like you can in excel. (Let’s ignore the useless pre-ooxml format encryption). A csv file is literally just a flat file - some strings on disk; there is no way to add encryption without wrapping it in _something_!